# MariaDB 10.3 vs 10.4 performance degradation

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

We're migrating to a new server and noticed some weird performance degradations. Old server is Ubuntu 18.04 running MariaDB 10.3 (10.3.27-MariaDB-1:10.3.27+maria~bionic-log); new is Ubuntu 20.04 running Mariadb 10.4 (10.4.33-MariaDB-1:10.4.33+maria~ubu2004-log). Hardware is also newer. We've built an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( SELECT product_id, purchase_id, SUM(qty) AS qty 
   FROM bq_purchaseitems GROUP BY purchase_id ) pi 
   LEFT JOIN bq_purchases pu ON pi.`purchase_id` = pu.id 
   LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM bq_products ) p ON p.id = pi.`product_id` 
WHERE p.id = 30242;
```

On MariaDB 10.3 we're getting the following:

```
Query_time: 2.992407  Lock_time: 0.000101  Rows_sent: 105  Rows_examined: 3625797
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 10461
# Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 4190240
# Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
```

However, on 10.4 we seen this:

```
# Query_time: 8.631189  Lock_time: 0.000274  Rows_sent: 105  Rows_examined: 3625797
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 10461
# Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 4190240
# Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
```

explain extended on 10.4

```
>explain extended SELECT * FROM    ( SELECT product_id, purchase_id, SUM(qty) AS qty     FROM bq_purchaseitems GROUP BY purchase_id ) pi     LEFT JOIN bq_purchases pu ON pi.`purchase_id` = pu.id     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM bq_products ) p ON p.id = pi.`product_id`  WHERE p.id = 30242;
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref            | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | bq_products      | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | const          | 1       |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL           | 2933042 |   100.00 | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | pu               | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | pi.purchase_id | 1       |   100.00 |             |
|    2 | DERIVED     | bq_purchaseitems | index  | NULL          | accountid | 4       | NULL           | 2933042 |   100.00 |             |
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

show warnings for the explain:

```
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `pi`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`pi`.`purchase_id` AS `purchase_id`,`pi`.`qty` AS `qty`,`pagony`.`pu`.`id` AS `id`,`pagony`.`pu`.`pid` AS `pid`,`pagony`.`pu`.`seller` AS `seller`,`pagony`.`pu`.`origin` AS `origin`,`pagony`.`pu`.`pos` AS `pos`,`pagony`.`pu`.`customer` AS `customer`,`pagony`.`pu`.`agent` AS `agent`,`pagony`.`pu`.`destination` AS `destination`,`pagony`.`pu`.`transaction_date` AS `transaction_date`,`pagony`.`pu`.`close_date` AS `close_date`,`pagony`.`pu`.`state` AS `state`,`pagony`.`pu`.`modifying` AS `modifying`,`pagony`.`pu`.`stock_reserved` AS `stock_reserved`,`pagony`.`pu`.`processable` AS `processable`,`pagony`.`pu`.`strict` AS `strict`,`pagony`.`pu`.`is_return` AS `is_return`,`pagony`.`pu`.`autocheckup` AS `autocheckup`,`pagony`.`pu`.`paid` AS `paid`,`pagony`.`pu`.`original_purchase_id` AS `original_purchase_id`,`pagony`.`pu`.`comment` AS `comment`,`pagony`.`pu`.`deleted` AS `deleted`,`pagony`.`pu`.`created_at` AS `created_at`,`pagony`.`pu`.`updated_at` AS `updated_at`,`pagony`.`pu`.`created_by` AS `created_by`,`pagony`.`pu`.`updated_by` AS `updated_by`,30242 AS `id`,30242 AS `base_product_id`,NULL AS `label_id`,'Matricás foglalkoztató - Állatokkal' AS `name`,NULL AS `display_name`,NULL AS `original_title`,7 AS `category_id`,327 AS `tradename_id`,'9071' AS `sku`,3070900090712 AS `barcode`,3490 AS `listprice`,NULL AS `b2b_price`,1 AS `currency`,215 AS `width`,230 AS `length`,NULL AS `height`,NULL AS `weight`,'My long description text cutted out' AS `description`,NULL AS `list_description`,NULL AS `pagenum`,NULL AS `cover`,NULL AS `pub_year`,900 AS `state`,0 AS `dividable`,NULL AS `voucher_type_id`,1 AS `active`,NULL AS `liquid_measure`,NULL AS `ntak_alkategoria_id`,'2021-04-23 10:08:43' AS `created_at`,'2024-02-08 15:15:50' AS `updated_at`,41 AS `created_by`,44 AS `updated_by`,1 AS `from_age`,3 AS `to_age`,NULL AS `gender_preference`,NULL AS `disc_number`,NULL AS `playtime`,NULL AS `player_number`,NULL AS `material`,NULL AS `size`,NULL AS `color`,NULL AS `series_id`,NULL AS `volume`,NULL AS `edition_number`,NULL AS `epub`,NULL AS `pdf`,NULL AS `audiobook` from (/* select#2 */ select `pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems`.`purchase_id` AS `purchase_id`,sum(`pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems`.`qty`) AS `qty` from `pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems` group by `pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems`.`purchase_id` having `pagony`.`bq_purchaseitems`.`product_id` = 30242) `pi` left join `pagony`.`bq_purchases` `pu` on(`pagony`.`pu`.`id` = `pi`.`purchase_id`) join `pagony`.`bq_products` where `pi`.`product_id` = 30242 |
```

SQL config is nearly identical, the 10.4 has more RAM, tmp is on ramdisk/tmpfs. What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you get the timing twice?  Was the system "cold" on the slower one?  Where other processes running?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` -- and look for `<expr_cache><`.

Comment: @RickJames no real difference if executed cold/hot/same session. I've added the explain to the post - explain shows same on 10.3 and 10.4 and there is no ```<expr_cache>``` in the warnings.

Comment: "Tmp_disk_tables: 0" -- The usage of a ramdisk or not is irrelevant.